# In Entity Framework, what is the parent type of all ObjectQuery fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I need to

```
OrderBy( p => new SomeClass {p.firstField, p.secondField} )
```

where

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{    T firstField {get;set;}
     T secondField {get;set;}
}
```

What is the most specific Entity Framework 4 type that T can be?
What code could I use to set firstField's and secondField's value?
(meaning I want firstField to reference p.ID and secondField to reference p.Name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the fields are the normal .NET types. This means that when `firstField` references to `ID`, this will probably be an `int` or a `Guid` and `secondField` will probably be a `string`.

If you are creating a generic class to do ordering with, this is not necessary. You can also do this:

```
OrderBy( p => new { p.ID, p.Name } )
```

This will automatically create a type for you.